# How to revert a Mercurial hg pull?

Tags: mercurial

If you do an `hg pull` and then an `hg update` (or an `hg merge`), is there a way to back this out?  Ie: revert your repository to the state prior to doing the `hg pull`?

I believe you can do `hg update -r n` where you would specify the changeset prior to the pull as `n`.  Though I'm guessing this will still leave the changesets in your repository but this isn't really what we want.  ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`hg strip` will remove revisions from a repository.  Like all powerful commands, its dangerous, so be careful.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension

Also see:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory

> If you catch your mistake immediately (or reasonably soon), you can just use ***hg strip REV*** to roll back the latest (one or more) changes. ...

Comment: Seems to work - `hg strip x` where `x` is the first changeset in the pull seems to do the trick.  After this `hg out` comes up empty which is what we want..

Comment: Cloning the repo to have a backup seems to be a good idea. SourceTree on OSX can Strip, accessed by right clicking a revision.

Comment: Why not just revert to the desired rev? Or does this actually kill history and that's desired over revert for some reason?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, you can't rollback because you've done a commit. What you can do is use 'hg strip' which is part of mq (after 2.8 strip is in it's own extension), or use mq to remove the changes. Either way I suggest you do everything on another clone, just in case.

To do strip, update to a revision that you want to keep, and then

```
hg strip <REV>
```

where `<REV>` is the first revision you want to remove. It will remove that one and all decendents (including your merge commit).

Alternatively you can

```
hg qnew (if you don't already have a patch queue)
hg qimport <REV>
```

which will import a single revision into the patch queue. You can then add more, and then use the mq commands to edit, rearrange, delete, or whatever you want to do with those revisions. `qdel` deletes the current patch.

---

Edit: Obviously, you'll need to enable the MQ extension for both of these, unless you're using 2.8 or later. In that case strip is in the strip extension, and mq in the mq extension. Both are shipped with the standard installation.

Answer (score 3):

`hg --rollback` can be used to undo the last transaction so as long as your `hg pull` is still the most recent transaction then you can use that. This command should be used with care though. See [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback) for some more details.

Comment: In my case I did a pull, a merge, then a commit (of the merge).  Then I realized I wanted to back ALL of this out.  `hg rollback` let me backout the commit but I can't see how to back out the pull..

Comment: There is one one level of rollback history so we'll have to see if anyone else posts a different suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can:

```
hg update -C <version>
```

see the mercurial [FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_want_to_retrieve_an_old_version_of_my_project.2C_what_do_I_do.3F).

Comment: That seems to update my working files to the state prior to the pull and merge.  BUT an `hg out` still shows the changesets I pulled down..  and an `hg push` would push those to the central repository which I do NOT want to do..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all traces of the pull form your history then you need to use an extension as Bert F  suggests (the philosophy in mercurial is to never change history)

if you dont mind history containing your mistake you have two slightly different options `hg update -C -r` which will create a new branch at the version you specify or `hg revert -r` which will stay on the same branch but create a new uncommited change undoing everything.