# How do i undo the hg pull and update?

Tags: mercurial, pull, revert

I am working in branch A and am using eclipse mercurial plugin to manage version control.Mistakely while pulling and updating the changes from the remote repository I pulled and updated changes of all the branches of my project.Now my branch A has changes of other branches say B , C , D .. as well.

I go-ogled and found out that hg rollback is likely the solution however I am not sure.

How do i undo my last pull and update? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 LB for the conciseness and wits.  What LazyBadger is saying is that pull and update may not do what you think they do...

Answer (score 0):

For a direct hands on [How to revert a Mercurial hg pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784265/how-to-revert-a-mercurial-hg-pull). Also look the [Mercurial FAQ (7.13).](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FTechnicalDetails.What_is_the_difference_between_rollback_and_strip.3F)

The `hg update` is never a problem, just do `hg update YOUR_LOVED_REVISION_NUMBER` and your  [working directory](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingDirectory) is again with all your stuff, and only your stuff.

Assuming you and only you works in the `A` branch, the `hg pull` is either a problem, just other's work in other's branches in your backstaged Mercurial internal history. If you like your [history (DAG)](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview) clean then you may `hg strip` those annoying branches in your **local** repository.

Assuming the `A` branch is co-worked, then the `hg pull` just imported the other's work to your local copy of the project.

Comment: `hg update` **can** be a problem if you forget to commit and have local changes.  The resolution is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392001/recover-from-hg-update-with-uncommitted-changes) and can be prevented by adding `update.check = noconflict` to the `[commands]` section in your `.hgrc` file.